# How to transfer a "link" to another component?

Tags: react-native

When I click on that touchable opacity I want to move to another component, fetch a "link" from API and transfer it to that other component. Can you give me some tips how to do this?

```
 componentDidMount(){
  fetch("https://trefle.io//api/plants?token=/////////////////&fbclid=IwAR3FY03yEVzS77Ca1Q9TIbMdMlJhXtpOjhcqcD-MJHAYJXCNcdA3UrJ2p9Q")
  .then(response => response.json())
 .then((responseJson)=> {
   this.setState({
    loading: false,
    plants: responseJson
   })
 })
 .catch(error=>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
 }


 renderItem=(data)=>

 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CatalogPlant', {data.item.link: link})} >
        <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={require('./images/flower.jpg')}/>
        <Text style={styles.cardText} >{data.item.scientific_name}</Text> 
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function for your fetch in your `CatalogPlant` component. And get the link from `navigation.getParam()`. for example:

```
myFetchFunction = () => {
    let {navigation} = this.props
    let data = navigation.getParam('data', false)
    if(data){
        let link = data.item.link
        // ...
    }
}
```

If navigation is undefined in CatalogPlant, You can use [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
renderItem = (data)=>{
 const {navigation} = this.props;
return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
         style={styles.card} 
         onPress={() => {
           navigation.navigate('CatalogPlant', data.item.link)
         }
        >
          <Image 
           style={styles.cardImage} 
           source={require('./images/flower.jpg')}
          />
          <Text 
           style={styles.cardText} 
          >
           {data.item.scientific_name}
          </Text> 
        </TouchableOpacity>
)

}
```

Comment: `data.item.link` must be an object.